# PreparedStatement.setNString flagging error

Tags: java, jdbc

I have an insert query that uses `PreparedStatement.setNString(int parameterIndex, String value)`. When the execution reached the statement the application gets hanged and after debugging and inspecting the statement it showed an error

```
method lookup failed for selector 'setNString' with signature '(ILjava/lang/String;)V.
```

I am connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Which version of the SQL Server driver are you using? Note there is no real reason to use `setNString` instead of `setString`.

Comment: Paste your code please.

Comment: Im using SQL server driver verison 4. I am using setNString as the string variables contain unicode characters. Here is my code 'pstmt.setNString(4,"test");'

Answer (score 0):

setNString is not implemented in most jdbc drivers, try to use setString.